# Is there a way to run tests for a 2GP package in development, without creating a new package version?

Tags: salesforcedx, 2gp, app-development, developer-productivity

I am developing a 2GP package. In order to run tests, I've had to create a new package version and install it in a scratch org (via sfdx). Is there a way to run tests after code changes without having to create a new package version, uninstall the old version from the scratch org, and install the new version in the scratch org?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your scratch org shouldn't be using `force:package:install` (now available without colons and taxonomy, such as `force package install`), but rather `force source push`. You can run the tests in that Scratch Org directly with `force apex test run` to verify that all your tests are running and have the appropriate coverage, or you can even run the tests in Salesforce's Developer Console. You should only create package versions when you're ready to create a new version for installation into other orgs.

Answer (score 1):

I disagree with the previous comment. Simply because "force package install" and "force source push" is not the same thing. For instance, my current master branch runs perfectly if pushed, but crashes when installed from the package version. Reason? Namespace. So in order to test your 2GP package you need to install it.

Comment: I am running into namespace-related issues as well while using the metadata API.